# How to install API 24?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install the cordova plugin for barcode scanning, but it gives me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK    components:
[Android SDK Platform 24].
```

Then I tried to install API 24 using Android SDK manager but it gives me the following message:

```
Package 'ARM 64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7' depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API 24'
```

I tried going to Packages -> Reload but it still gives me the same message. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you are trying to install system image for Android API 24. But you need SDK Platform Android, API 24. Try to install that one.

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks. i tried clearing up the cache and reloading packages but android 7.0's SDK platform doesnt still show up.. is there any way to install it other than sdk manager?

Comment: I think in you Android SDK manager having some pending updates like Android SDK tool or any other try to update them first. and sdk platform 24 will be appeared after update them.